# Fazer um vetor genérico em Java

Tags: java, array, classes, estrutura-de-dados, genéricos

Como criar um vetor dinâmico em Java com programação genérica? Esse vetor precisa ter tamanho inicial de tamanho 4 e ser aumentado seu tamanho na medida que novos elementos precisarem ser inseridos.

A classe precisa ter:

- Construtor Padrão.
- Construtor com parâmetro tamanho inicial do vetor
- bool remove (elemento)
- bool add(Elemento)
- elemento First()
- elemento Last()
- bool search(elemento)
- int size()
- string print().

O que já fiz até agora:

```
package atividade;

public class Vetor<T> {

    T[] vetor;
    int qntElementos = 0;
    public Vetor(int tam) {
        vetor = (T[]) new Object[tam];
    }
    public boolean vazio() {
        return Tamanho() == 0;
    }
    public void Adicionar(T elemento) {
        if (Tamanho() == vetor.length) {
            redimensionar();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            if (vetor[i] == null) {
                vetor[i] = (T) elemento;
                qntElementos++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Remover(int posicao) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (vazio()) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Vazio");
        }
        if (posicao < vetor.length) {
            vetor[posicao] = null;
            qntElementos--;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Posição inexistente!!!");
        }
    }

    public void RemoverInicio() {
        if (vazio()) {
            System.out.println("Vetor vazio!");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            if (vetor[i] != null) {
                vetor[i] = null;
                break;
            }
            qntElementos--;
        }
    }

    public void RemoverFim() {
        if (vazio()) {
            System.out.println("Vetor vazio!");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            if (vetor[i] == null) {
                vetor[i - 1] = null;
            }
            qntElementos--;
            break;
        }
        vetor[Tamanho()] = null;
    }

    public int Tamanho() {
        return qntElementos;
    }

    public void Limpar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            if (vetor[i] != null) {
                vetor[i] = null;
                qntElementos--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void redimensionar(){
        T[] novoVetor = (T[]) new Object[vetor.length * 2];
        if(vetor.length == Tamanho()){
            for(int i =0; i < vetor.length; i++){
                novoVetor[i] = vetor[i];
            }
            vetor = novoVetor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que você já fez? Qual a dúvida específica que tem?

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Acho que aqui `vetor = (T[]) new Object[tam];` o correto seria `vetor =  new T[tam];`, já que T será um Object, mas nem sempre o contrario será verdadeiro.

Comment: @DiegoF também achei, mas Java não permite isto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu dei uma melhorada e resolvo alguns problemas, muitos até de sintaxe. Fiz alguns métodos extras, que estavam no enunciado e outros que podem ser úteis. Adotei o estilo típico m Java, mas não mudei os nomes de métodos e funções que julgo não ser os melhores. E fiz algumas coisas que acho mais adequado em cada situação. Normalmente eu melhoraria outras coisas, mas já mexi demais. Não garanto que está tudo ok, mas fiz um teste básico. Obviamente a implementação é um pouco ingênua.

Gostaria que o Java tivesse uma forma melhor de lidar com genericidade. Até tem melhorar um pouco com reflexão que eu preferi evitar. Pelo menos usei `Comparable` no lugar de `Object` para limitar um pouco mais.

```
class Vector<T> {
    T[] vetor;
    int qntElementos = 0;
    public Vector(int tam) {
        vetor = (T[]) new Comparable[tam];
    }
    public Vector() {
        this(4);
    }
    public void adicionar(T elemento) {
        if (tamanho() == vetor.length) redimensionar();
        vetor[tamanho()] = elemento;
        qntElementos++;
    }
    public T pegar(int posicao) {
        if (vazio() || posicao < 0 || posicao >= tamanho()) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Posição fora da faixa permitida");
        return vetor[posicao];
    }
    public T pegarPrimeiro() {
        if (vazio()) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Posição fora da faixa permitida");
        return vetor[0];
    }
    public T pegarUltimo() {
        if (vazio()) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Posição fora da faiza permitida");
        return vetor[qntElementos - 1];
    }
    public int procurar(T elemento) {
        for (int i = 0; i < qntElementos; i++) {
            if (vetor[i].equals(elemento)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public boolean removerElemento(T elemento) {
        return remover(procurar(elemento));
    }
    public boolean remover(int posicao) {
        if (!vazio() && posicao >= 0 && posicao < tamanho()) {
            for (int i = posicao; i < qntElementos; i++) vetor[i] = vetor[i + 1];
            vetor[tamanho()] = null;
            qntElementos--;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean removerInicio() {
        if (vazio()) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < qntElementos; i++) vetor[i] = vetor[i + 1];
        qntElementos--;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean removerFim() {
        if (vazio()) return false;
        vetor[tamanho()] = null;
        qntElementos--;
        return true;
    }
    public int tamanho() {
        return qntElementos;
    }
    public boolean vazio() {
        return tamanho() == 0;
    }
    public void limpar() {
        vetor = (T[]) new Comparable[4];
    }
    private void redimensionar() {
        T[] novoVetor = (T[]) new Comparable[vetor.length * 2];
        if (vetor.length == tamanho()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) novoVetor[i] = vetor[i];
            vetor = novoVetor;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/i69gaD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/debrvjce-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Vector.java).

Comment: Muito obrigado, ja me ajudou mto.. como faço pra pegar o primeiro e o ultimo elemento da lista? e fazer uma busca binaria de um elemento da lista?

Comment: @CarlosDiego Mudei o que estava na pergunta. A busca binária não estava. Seria bom fazer outra pergunta. Teria que garantir que o vetor esteja ordenado para fazer a busca binária. O que é algo meio esquisito de fazer, o ideal )mas não obrigatório) é ter uma estrutura completamente diferente. Dê uma olhada no [tour], agora você pode votar em tudo no site.

Comment: @bigown, seria possível, ao invés de rescrever tudo, herdar de Collection e sobrescrever apenas os métodos que não tem, mantendo ainda uma lista genérica ?

Comment: @PauloGustavo Seria. É o que eu faria. Mas todos os métodos teria que ser escritos já que `Collection` é uma interface, portanto não há implementação dos métodos, só os contratos. Tem várias melhorias que poderiam ser feitas nesta classe se ela fosse usada de verdade. Só não faz muito sentido. No fundo esta classe está reimplementando a `ArrayList`. Só é interessante fazer isto como exercício.