# É possível criar uma lista de Objeto genérico

Tags: java, genéricos

Preciso gerar uma lista genérica

```
List<?> listaGenerica;
```

tendo como parâmetro uma string com o caminho da classe, como mostrado abaixo.

```
Class class = Class.forName("com.teste.Endereco");
```

Isso é possível?

Desculpe a confusão na descrição da pergunta pois eu estou confuso mesmo..kkk

Tenho a seguinte classe de entidade do hibernate.

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonbEndereco", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class})
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "teste")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "teste_id_seq", sequenceName = "teste_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Teste implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6800342991944554204L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "teste_id_seq")
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    @Type(type = "jsonbEndereco")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonbEndereco")
    private List<Endereco> enderecos;
```

ao converter para lista de endereços, ele converte todos os campos como string, não permitindo o typecast pata endereço.

```
OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(string, clazz);
```

Isso porque o clazz vem como java.util.List

Resouvi este problema ao usar a lista onde sei que é uma List com o seguinte código.

```
Teste teste = testeCTR.carregar(1);

Endereco endereco = null;    

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Endereco> enderecos = mapper.convertValue(teste.getEnderecos(), new TypeReference<List<Endereco>>() {});
```

Minha intenção era passar como parâmetro br.com.jenkins.Endereco

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonbEndereco", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class, parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = JsonBinaryType.CLASS, value = "br.com.jenkins.Endereco")})
})
```

e ao converter o json queria converter e mapear corretamente.

```
OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(string, new TypeReference<List<com.teste.Endereco>>() {});
```

me desculpe se ainda esta confuso...

**[Resolvido em partes]**

Criar o lista de objetos a partir de um Type de uma classe eu não consegui...
Mas contornei o erro Criando uma classe ListaEndereco que contem uma  lista de endereço, e dessa forma funcionou.

```
public class ListaEndereco {
    private List<Endereco> enderecos;

    public List<Endereco> getEnderecos() {
        return enderecos;
    }

    public void setEnderecos(List<Endereco> enderecos) {
        this.enderecos = enderecos;
    }
}


public class Endereco {
    private Integer enderecoid;
    private String endereco;

    public Integer getEnderecoid() {
        return enderecoid;
    }

    public void setEnderecoid(Integer enderecoid) {
        this.enderecoid = enderecoid;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
}

Type type = ListaEndereco.class;



 String json = "{\"enderecos\": [{\"endereco\": \"Teste\", \"enderecoid\": 1}, {\"endereco\": \"Teste2\", \"enderecoid\": 2}, {\"endereco\": \"Teste3\", \"enderecoid\": 3}]}";       
    ListaEndereco lista = (ListaEndereco) OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(json, type.getClass());
```

Muito obrigado a todos. Pela ajuda

Comment: `List<T> listaGenerica = new ArrayList<Endereco>();` assim?

Comment: Semelhante http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126968/fazer-um-vetor-gen%C3%A9rico-em-java/

Comment: Se entendi direito e precisa de uma estrutura chave/valor, precisa então de um `Map`, não `List`. Senão, pode usar `List<Object>`, afinal toda classe Java é subclasse de object implicitamente.

Comment: @PauloGustavo Tipo isso [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355311/using-and-declaring-generic-listt)? Olhe a resposta.

Comment: É que eu queria passar por parâmetro no  Annotations "com.teste.Endereco" e criar esta lista para fazer uma conversão correta do objeto. tipo assim List<Endereco> enderecos = mapper.convertValue(teste.getEnderecos(), new TypeReference<List<Endereco>>() {
        });

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o que você deseja no enunciadoda pergunta?

Comment: @JoseAndersonPereira modifiquei o enunciado. Conseguiu entender agora... Preciso instanciar uma classe e não um objeto...

Comment: @renan talvez isso resolveria o meu problema tbm... meu problema q quando converto o json ele retorna listas de endereços mas todos os campos como String, então não consigo fazer o typeacast

Answer (score 2):

Sim é possivel.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.teste.Endereco");

List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
classes.add(clazz);
```

Comment: precisava pegar a referencia de uma lista de um objeto especifico
TypeReference type = new TypeReference<List<Endereco>>() { };