# Problema na impressão de um vetor

Tags: java, array

Pessoal estou com um problema básico que não consigo entender o erro:

Classe Prova:

```
public class Prova {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vetor lista = new Vetor();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int codigo, idade;

        Dados dado = new Dados();

        System.out.println("Digite o código da idade: ");
        codigo = scan.nextInt();
        dado.setCodigo(codigo);

        System.out.println("Digite a idade da pessoa: ");
        idade = scan.nextInt();
        dado.setIdade(idade);

        lista.add(dado);

        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

Classe Vetor:

```
public class Vetor {

private Dados[] dados = new Dados[100];
private int total = 0;

public void add(Dados item){

    for(int i = 0; i < this.dados.length; i++){
        this.dados[this.total] = item;
        this.total++;

    }
  }
}
```

Classe Dados:

```
public class Dados {

private int cod, idade;

public int getCodigo(){
    return this.cod;
}

public int getIdade(){
    return this.idade;
}

public void setCodigo(int cod){
    this.cod = cod;
}

public void setIdade(int idade){
    this.idade = idade;
}

}
```

O problema é que na minha saída está assim:
prova.Vetor@89cf1e

Não sei como fazer para sair com string. O que está faltando, como resolvo?

Comment: Você precisa de um laço pra percorrer item a item um vetor e exibi-los de forma individual. Mas esse metodo add, se você controla o total separado, pra que usar for? Basta checar se total alcançou o tamanho -1 do vetor

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126968/fazer-um-vetor-gen%C3%A9rico-em-java

Comment: Ok, entendi que não é necessário o uso do for no método add, mas não entendi o uso do for para percorrer os valores

Comment: Veja o exemplo da resposta que eu postei o link. Você precisa criar métodos na classe vetor que retornei um item informado um indice, e outro que retorne o tamanho dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> O problema é que na minha saída está assim: prova.Vetor@89cf1e

Quando você manda imprimir o vetor com o `System.out.println(lista)` é o nome do objeto e o identity hash code que costuma ser o seu endereço de memória. Isso ocorre porque o seu método toString não foi implementado para se comportar de forma diferente. Para que você imprima os valores do seu vetor, basta sobrescrever esse método na sua classe Vetor. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
class Vetor {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String vetorTexto = "";
        for (Dados dado : dados) {
             vetorTexto += dado.toString() + " ";
        }
        return vetorTexto;
    }  
}
```

A classe `Dados` implementaria o `toString` para retornar as informações no formato desejado (e.g. codigo, codigo + idade, ...):

```
class Dados {
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return codigo + "-" + idade; //Exemplo: formata o objeto um código-idade.
   }
}
```

Comment: A solução é essa mesmo, mas fazer no `toString()` eu não gosto não. Não tenho certeza se é normal fazer isso em Java, se for, achei mais um motivo para não gostar da linguagem. Em outras linguagens se considera um abuso do mecanismo já que esse método é para imprimir a identidade mesmo e não uma representação dos dados.

Comment: Interessante sua observação. Conceitualmente seria errado abusar disso, mas sugeri o toString por ser algo mais transparente para o print. Se eu fosse implementar faria uma classe utilitária para realizar a impressão dos dados.

Answer (score 1):

Como você está implementando uma classe Vetor, seria interessante que a torne capaz de retornar essas informações de forma individual. Como eu disse nos comentários e está sugerido [**este link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126968/fazer-um-vetor-gen%C3%A9rico-em-java), você pode adicionar um método que retorne um item e outro que retorne o tamanho, para que a opção de exibir um ou todos seja de quem está usando a classe:

```
public int tamanho(){
    return total;
}

public Dados retornarElemento(int indice){
   if(indice >= total){
     throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Indice fora do intervalo do vetor");
   }
  return dados[i];
}
```

No `main`, você faz um laço pegando o tamanho e varrendo até o ultimo indice adicionado:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lista.tamanho(); i++){
    //retornarElemento() retorna um tipo Dados, por isso a chamada direta
    System.out.println(lista.retornarElemento(i).getCodigo());
    System.out.println(lista.retornarElemento(i).getIdade());
}
```

Pode parecer mais complexo, mas dá mais flexibilidade de uso da sua classe Vetor, permitindo saber a qualquer momento quantos itens foram adicionados, e recuperar um item individual(quando já se conhece seu indice) sem ter que usar laço.

---

Vale lembrar que seu método add pode melhorar, trocando o laço por verificações condicionais em relação a sua capacidade(se está cheio demais).